# Delete a row if it doesn't occur in both tables (delete orphaned rows)

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to delete an any rows in `banners` if it doesn't have a corresponding row in `banners_pp`

How do I do the `{doesn't exist}` part?

```
DELETE banners.* FROM banners
LEFT JOIN banners_pp
USING(banner_id)
WHERE banners_pp.banner_id {doesn't exist}
```

Comment: You should use foreign keys in the future to avoid having to delete orphaned rows at all.

Comment: i didn't make the db, i'm just trying to clean the crap out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM banners
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM banners_pp
    WHERE banner_id  = banners.banner_id 
)
```

see [more](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-delete-records-in-one-table-not-in-another/) details

Answer (score 1):

Use `WHERE banners_pp.banner_id IS NULL`

In a `LEFT JOIN`, rows from the left table (`banners`) that do not have corresponding rows in the right table (`banners_pp`) are present but have `NULL` in the columns of the right table. If there is no entry in `banners_pp` having `banner_id = 2` but an entry in `banners` having `banner_id = 2`, the corresponding row in the joined table could look somewhat like this:

```
 | banners.banner_id | banners.foo | banners_pp.banner_id | banners_pp.bar |
 |         2         |     x       |         NULL         |        NULL    |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE 
 FROM banners
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SElect 1 from banners_pp
          WHERE banners_pp.banner_id = banners.banner_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DELETE FROM banners
WHERE banner_id NOT IN (
SELECT banner_id
FROM banners_pp
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM banners b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM banners_pp bp
    WHERE bp.banner_id  = b.banner_id 
)
```